# How to bulk access houndreds of email accounts on POP3?

Tags: email, email-client, email-server

I have 500 email accounts from different providers, what easy way there is to access all of them together without the need to add manually each account on an email client?

Could be a good solution if there is an email client that permit adding email account on bulk, to paste all 500 email id and passwords.

Do you know any?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you have some way of accessing all accounts like a file of usernames, passwords, and mail hosts you could write a little script to use `fetchmail` or similar

Comment: It would help if you could mention the OS the software should run on, and your price limit in case it comes to paid solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually ***need*** 500 accounts? Strange daze indeed

Comment: @ivanivan I'm interested on your solution. How can I write the script to use fetchmail or similar? Any reference or more information?